# Representing pregnancy on LEGO minifigs without a dome

Tags: building, minifigures

So far for pregnancy I have tried a fetal carrier that I put on the minifig's back but this limits her movements. Specifically she can't bend too far in either direction and also she can't lay down the way she normally would (she would have to like bend her legs when she lays down or something to keep the fetus inside).

My minifigs don't have a hole in the belly where I can put a big white dome to illustrate pregnancy.

So what is the best way to show pregnancy without a pregnancy dome?

Comment: I sincerely wish I understood what you were asking here, but I just don't get it. Are you trying to make a minifig look pregnant? I would generally ask for photos of what you have tried already, but in this case, I must admit that I'm a bit hesitant - I don't want to frighten the children! Please do clarify, what movements does the "fetal carrier" restrict (and what is one of those, anyway?) And why, oh why, did you put your the mother in a "pen" that looks like a jail cell? The mind boggles. :-) BTW Welcome to this site. I hope you find it useful.

Comment: This is the absolute strangest question I have seen here. I don't even know what to start. Fetal carrier, pen, jail-cell, pieces coming off violently during birth, pregnancy dome???!!! This makes me scared! :(

Comment: I have voted to close as "unclear what you're asking". Please edit your question to clarify and to provide more context.

Comment: What about using one of those pieces that goes over the head peg so you can attach a backpack, except hang it on the front side and attach a dome that way instead?

Comment: I've removed the elements of the question relating to the pen/crib as they don't seem relevant to the main part of the question. I'm assuming that you're also looking for a sort of "easy access display area" to hold this minifig which might be better suited to a different question.

Comment: Kit Z Fox, the neck bracket does not fit over the pants peg.

Answer (score 8):

[image: pregnant minifig using inverted round slide/tile]

The best piece to represent a round belly is the "Plate, Round 2 x 2 with Rounded Bottom" (part 2654). The "dome" pieces are way too big. Connect the rounded bottom plate to the bottoms of two "Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Headlight" bricks (part 4070), also known as the Erling brick. Use short legs to get the total height right.

Note that the pegs on the leg pieces are slightly larger than a normal stud, so they make for a *very* tight fit in the back of the Erling brick. They do fit with some force, and they are difficult to remove.

FYI, I experimented with a few iterations, including one using a 2x2 flat tile on a bracket, and this was the version that had my non-Lego fan wife exclaim, "Oh yeah, that looks good!"

Comment: This version cannot bend her legs, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, most LEGO pregnancies appear to cheat, using glue or Blu Tack to attach the various elements on to the stomach of the minifig.

One example I've seen is the use of a 1x2 tile, as seen here at the [Brick Testament](http://www.thebricktestament.com/the_life_of_jesus/jesus_is_born_02/mt01_18.html):

[image: Joseph surprised by Mary's miraculous pregnancy]

In this image, Mary could be holding the tile in place, but [in other images](http://www.thebricktestament.com/the_life_of_jesus/jesus_is_born_02/lk01_56.html), her hands are not near enough.

Also to your point of lying down - in real life I've noticed that some pregnant women prefer to lay on their sides rather than their backs, certainly during the later stages of pregnancy.

Comment: I can't get neck brackets to fit over the minifig hip studs.

Comment: Hmm, curious I'll have another go - I'm sure I've done something similar in the past...

Comment: They do not fit. The leg pegs are slightly larger than a stud. (This is also why the use of slopes as skirts results in a loose connection.)

Answer (score 3):

One alternative is to use an appropriate decal rather than trying to construct something.

[image: Pregnant Minifig]

Image courtesy [Flikr](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CAUQjhw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fphotos%2Fpraiter_yed%2Fsets%2F72157627178035018%2Fdetail%2F&ei=QvXUVLeQLs_jao7wgrgL&bvm=bv.85464276,d.ZGU&psig=AFQjCNHP5iqXArHX9uiJZ4xrd2mOSF9cYg&ust=1423328960202288).

Answer (score -1):

I usually hang the minifig back plate with knob on the front with a dome, or I use two between the torso and legs (they will fit) and attach a dome or something else.