# How is this brick attached to the pregnant minifig?

Tags: building, minifigures

While Google-image-searching pregnant minifigs ([don't ask](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4891/lego-pregnancy-without-a-dome)) I came across this fig, and other variations on it, but I can't figure out how the 2x2 round brick is attached.[image]

Comment: I'd hazard a guess at glue or Blu Tack...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They used an adhesive of some sort. You can see from the side that the piece is attached flush to the body of the minifig, and there is no additional gap between the torso and legs pieces to account for any sort of bracket.

Answer (score -2):

Could be done with 2 brackets I guess (part# 42446).

[image]

holes over the leg-studs.

Comment: I don't have a huge quantity of those parts, but the ones I have, of various ages, do not fit on any of my minifig's hips. The studs on the hips are thicker than the regular studs.

Comment: I don't have these brackets at all so I'm not able to check it out. A standard 2x1 brick will fit over the studs on the hips. But you did check it with brackets right?

Comment: I tried several brackets on my newest and oldest (30 years old) minifigs at hand. None fit.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, we remain in mystery then at least for now.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 How close are they to fitting?  Would a small amount of modification allow them to fit?  That might be what we're looking at.

Comment: @Nick2253 On my older minifig they fit slightly better; I can jam the bracket down about 1mm. If the leg studs or the bracket were shaved a bit, it could be made to work, but I'm not willing to test that.

Comment: What about putting the lady in a dress by using a slope instead of legs? It does restrict movement, but the brackets would then work.

Comment: You would be able to see those brackets, both from the side as well as the front in the corners of the dome. That's clearly not what is being used here.